# Javascript: How to have value in string represented by %s and then replaced with a value

Tags: javascript

I know this a really stupid question.

I've had a good few years experience with javascript but this one thing seems to have skipped my mind, my head has gone blank and I can't remember what it's called and how I would go about doing it.

Basically what I'm looking for is when you have a string variable such as:

```
var error_message = "An account already exists with the email: %s"
```

And you then pass a string somehow into this and it replaces the %s.

I probably sound really idiotic, but I'd really appreciate the help / reminding!

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just use the `replace` method:

```
error_message = error_message.replace('%s', email);
```

This will only replace the first occurance, if you want to replace multiple occurances, you use a regular expression so that you can specify the global (g) flag:

```
error_message = error_message.replace(/%s/g, email);
```

Answer (score 11):

Please find an example below, thanks.

```
/**
 * @param  {String} template
 * @param  {String[]} values
 * @return {String}
 */
function sprintf(template, values) {
  return template.replace(/%s/g, function() {
    return values.shift();
  });
}
```

Example usage:

```
sprintf('The quick %s %s jumps over the lazy %s', [
  'brown',
  'fox',
  'dog'
]);
```

Would output:

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

Answer (score 10):

'Modern' ES6 solution: use *template literals*. Note the backticks!

```
var email = 'somebody@example.com';
var error_message = `An account already exists with the email: ${email}`;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Note: this only works if `email` is within scope. If you plan to save off formatted messages in another context (such as i18n or resource file) this won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at this : http://www.devbox.info/javascript-sprintf.html

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely bookmark this for future reference. That's where I got confused, between PHP and Javascript, thinking that there was a built in function. For the current project simply using the replace function will suffice.

Comment: recommending to close since the link is broken, removing any value from this answer

Comment: Link appears to be up at this time.   It appears to be a reasonable sprintf implementation.   Not sure it is possible to include the 'essential parts' without including the whole thing.

Comment: "Content blocked by your organisation" - This Websense category is filtered: Adult Material.

Thanks a lot,  corporate IT!

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a new function to handle this:

```
function sprint(str, o) {
    if (typeof str !== "string" || typeof o !== "object") {
        return;
    }
    var regex = /%s\(([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15})\)/g,
        i;
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        str = str.replace(regex, function (found, match) {
            return o[match];
        });
    } else {
        for (i in o) {
            str = str.replace(/%s/, o[i]);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

And a few tests:

```
// Ordered Array mode
var s0 = sprint("This is %s %s call, using an %s in order", ["a", "function", "array"]);

// Ordered|Unordered Obejct Literal mode
var s1 = sprint("This is a %s(sw) function, %s(ma)! You need to %s(ch) this out...", {
    ma: "mang",
    sw: "sweet", //This is purposely out of order
    ch: "check"
});

console.log(s0);
console.log(s1);
```

https://gist.github.com/mbjordan/5807011

Comment: Thanks it works. Very useful when you have an array of strings to map for each %s %s %s...

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own `sprintf` function:

```
function sprintf(str, ...args) {
  return args.reduce((_str, val) => _str.replace(/%s|%v|%d|%f|%d/, val), str);
}
const s  = sprintf("An account already exists with the email: %s", "SOME_ERROR");
console.log(s); // "An account already exists with the email: SOME_ERROR"

// OR bind this function in String's prototype

String.prototype.sprintf = function (...args) {
  return args.reduce((_str, val) => _str.replace(/%s|%v|%d|%f/, val), this);
};

const str = "one %s, two %d, three %v".sprintf(1, 2, 3);
console.log(str) // "one: 1, two: 2, three: 3"
```

you can pass multiple `%s or %v or %d`

```
const str2 = sprintf("one %s, two %d, three %v", 1, 2, 3)
console.log(str2); // "one: 1, two: 2, three: 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing quite like C's `printf()` or PHP's `sprintf()` functionality built into JavaScript. There is the `replace()` method of the string object which can be used to *replace* one thing with another - which could be used in this particular case, but it's limited.

There are several implementations around that others have written which cover a subset of `sprintf()`'s behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
var error_message = "An account already exists with the email: %s"

var myNewString = error_message.replace(" %s", newdata);
```

Example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var visitorName = "Chuck";
var myOldString = "Hello username! I hope you enjoy your stay username.";
var myNewString = myOldString.replace("username", visitorName);

document.write("Old string =  " + myOldString); 
document.write("<br />New string = " + myNewString);

</script>
```

Output for above.

Old string = Hello username! I hope you enjoy your stay username.
New string = Hello Chuck! I hope you enjoy your stay username.